# if statement unable to check the value

Tags: c

can someone tell me what's wrong with this code. The value is being stored in 'ch' but if statement is unable to validate it.

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
            if (ch == 4){
                    printf("Correct Answer \n");
                    score++;
            }
            else{
                    printf("Wrong Answer \n");
            }
```

Comment: You probably want to check the digit `'4'`, not the numerical value (ASCII) `4` of the character. Use `ch=='4'` instead.

Comment: The `%c` format is to read a *character*. The value `4` is an *`int`*. There's no encoding where `'4' == 4`.

Comment: Those are answers.

Comment: As a different solution: `int number; if (scanf("%d", &number) == 1) { if (number == 4) { ... } }`

Answer (score 1):

`%c` means you are expecting a character.
So a 4 you input, is not an integer `4`, but a character `'4'`.

Simply check for `ch == '4'`

Answer (score 0):

Note that `char` is a numeric type, so this will compile and run, but not do what's expected because we've read a char (with format specifier `%c` into a char variable `ch`, but then compare it to the number `4` rather than the character `'4'`.

You should also get in the habit of checking the return value of `scanf` as a failure to read into `ch` if it's uninitialized will lead to unexpected behavior.

```
if (scanf(" %c", &ch) != 1) {
    // Something to handle the error.
}

if (ch == '4') {
    printf("Correct Answer \n");
    score++;
}
else {
    printf("Wrong Answer \n");
}
```